# Rsync recursively only new directories

Tags: recursion, backup, rsync

I am developing my backup [pet project](https://github.com/administratorius/LitBackup) and can't find a rsync feature I desperately need.

Imagine this:

```
parent1/
        dir1/
            file1

parent2/
       dir2/
            file2
```

If I move "dir1" to "parent2" like this:

```
parent1/


parent2/
       dir1/
            file1
       dir2/
            file2
```

it leaves no other option than to recursively sync `parent2/`, otherwise `file1` will be omitted. What I want to do is force rsync to recursively sync newly created `dir1`, but omit `dir2`

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't that require rsync to track newly added files and exclude them by default?  That's just beyond the scope of rsync.  But you could implement that tracking as part of your program.  Arq does that, I just don't know what the default behavior is if something is moved... http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/

Comment: I just spotted a error in my question (fixed), I want to exclude unchanged directories from recursion and only recurse new directory.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem possible as `rsync` need to go in each folder to see what has changed.

The best option remains the `--update` one, in order to *not* transfer all files, and skip any files which exist on the destination and have a modified time that is newer than the source file.

---

Another option:

For text files, a source control system like [Git](http://git-scm.com/) would indeed ignore `dir2`, as it would detect its associated SHA1 hasn't change (no need to go in that folder).